# error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my code.

```
void viewall(struct student st[], int itemcount)
{
    int i = 0;
    cout << left << setw(5) << "ID" << setw(20) << "NAME" << setw(5) << "SEX"
            << setw(5) << "Q1" << setw(5) << "Q2" << setw(5) << "AS" << setw(5)
            << "MI" << setw(5) << "FI" << setw(5) << "TOTAL" << "\n";
    cout
            << "========================================================================\n";

    while (i <= itemcount)
    {

        if (st[i].stnumber != "")
        {

            cout << left << setw(5) << st[i].stnumber << setw(20)
                    << st[i].stname << setw(5) << st[i].sex << setw(5)
                    << st[i].quiz1 << setw(5) << st[i]quiz2 << setw(5) 
                    << st[i].assignment << setw(5) << st[i].midterm
                    << setw(5) << st[i].finale << setw(5) << st[i].total
                    << "\n";
        }

        i = i + 1;
    }

}
```

---

`error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’`    <---- That's the error i got,what should i do?

Comment: That's not the full error message.

Comment: The long lines and poor indentation made the error harder to spot than it needed to be. Good code style can stop a lot of bugs before they happen.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a typo:

> [...] << st[i]quiz2 << [...]

It should more likely be:

> [...] << st[i].quiz2 << [...]

Note the `.` (dot)